# 2D Array where every element is a class element

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I am using the following way to create a 2D array where every element is a class element

```
var Width: int = 10
var Heigth: int = 10

class ABC {
    var A: Int = 0
    var B: Int = 0
    var C: Int = 0
}

var MABC = [[ABC]] (count: Width, repeatedValue: [ABC](count:Heigth, repeatedValue: ABC()))
```

and the following expression to change a value of one of the elements.

```
MABC[0][0].A = 1
```

but when I do that, the property A of all matriz elements is changed from 0 to 1, not only in the element [0][0].

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it is nothing wrong. you fill your array with the same reference value, so all items in the array represents the same class ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var Width: Int = 10
var Heigth: Int = 10

class ABC {
    var A: Int = 0
    var B: Int = 0
    var C: Int = 0
}

var MABC = [[ABC]] (count: Width, repeatedValue: [ABC](count:Heigth, repeatedValue: ABC()))
MABC.forEach { (arr) -> () in
    dump(UnsafePointer<ABC>(arr))
}
/*
▿ UnsafePointer(0x7FF4C0C36C20)
- pointerValue: 140689182780448
▿ UnsafePointer(0x7FF4C0C36C20)
- pointerValue: 140689182780448
▿ UnsafePointer(0x7FF4C0C36C20)
- pointerValue: 140689182780448
.....
*/
```

check the addresses of each element in you array. you did pass the same reference to each element of the array ...

use value type to fill your array

```
var Width: Int = 10
var Heigth: Int = 10

struct ABC {
    var A: Int = 0
    var B: Int = 0
    var C: Int = 0
}

var MABC = [[ABC]] (count: Width, repeatedValue: [ABC](count:Heigth, repeatedValue: ABC()))
MABC[0][0].A = 1
dump(MABC)

....▿ 10 elements
  ▿ [0]: 10 elements
    ▿ [0]: ABC
      - A: 1
      - B: 0
      - C: 0
    ▿ [1]: ABC
      - A: 0
      - B: 0
      - C: 0
    ▿ [2]: ABC
      - A: 0
      - B: 0
      - C: 0
.......
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know how to solve the problem. I have an array MABC of 10 x 10 elements and every element is an element of type ABC.

Comment: using struct as MABC will help you to use an extra copy of it in each element of an array. or you can create an empty array first and add new instance of MABC class in a cycle.